# Can't get AccuWeather API to work correctly

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, url

Ok, so I'm trying to build a weather app that gives you the current temp and future cast for the following 5 days based off your zipcode. The problem is accuweather searched based on their own codes per region and the only was I can search for zipcode is using there locations search which is just info about the area. I've been trying to work with the url for a while now. Any help is appreciated. Also I'll re insert the dummy text for the api key. I tried inserting the "currentconditions" key in over the "locations" and its just an error. There has to be a way to search for weather with your zip. Any help is appreciated!

URL: http://dataservice.accuweather.com/locations/v1/postalcodes/search?apikey={api key here}&q=28124

Comment: Can you show us the full request in your code?

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 1):

You need to first retrieve the unique key that represents a given zip code via the `locations` service, and then you can get forecast data for that key with the `currentconditions` service.

The following example uses jquery to interact with the api and obtain the current temperature for my location:

```
const baseurl = 'http://dataservice.accuweather.com';
const apikey  = 'YOUR_API_KEY';

$.getJSON(`${baseurl}/locations/v1/postalcodes/search`, {
    'apikey': apikey,
    'q': '18612'
}).then(function (locData) {
    return $.getJSON(`${baseurl}/currentconditions/v1/${locData[0].Key}`, {
        'apikey': apikey
    });
}).then(function (tempData) {
    const temp = tempData[0].Temperature.Imperial;
    console.log(`${temp.Value}${temp.Unit}`);
});
```

Result:

```
26F
```